# Access DB - operation must use an updateable query

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have an table where i need to update the user's password where the username is store in a session. However, i got this error: "operation must use an updateable query" even though i have granted all users and administrators full control.

The following is my codes:

```
string str = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfolder\mydatabase";
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(str))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [users] SET [password] = ? WHERE username = ?";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Request.Form["conPassword"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = (string)Session["username"];
    con.Open();
    try
    {
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         MessageBox.Show("Your password has been changed successfully.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
         con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your user have a permission to modify this access file?

Comment: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfolder\mydatabase` Is this code running in the context of an IIS application? Because you'll need to make sure that the application pool identity can write to this file.

Comment: Yes, i have already grant full control for all users under my folder and database. But it doesn't work

Comment: It's definitely permissions on the folder (remember Access needs to create a lock file as well), double, triple check the folder permissions! Grant `everyone` full control and reduce permissions from there.